# How to delete a specific exe file via batch which can be stored anywhere on the computer?

Tags: batch-file

So short from writing out every possible file path. Is there a way to delete a specific exe file that could be anywhere on the computer?

```
C:
del C:\Users\Student\Downloads\blah.exe
del C:\Users\Student\Documents\blah.exe
del C:\Users\Student\music\blah.exe
```

Comment: What you mean by *any where on the computer*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command prompt window and execute there `del /?`

You get displayed the help for command **del** listing also parameter `/S` for deleting all files matching the file name or file name pattern in all subdirectories.

For example `blah.exe` is deleted in all subdirectories on drive C: with following command:

```
del /F /Q /S C:\blah.exe
```

Excepted are all directories with no permissions for deletion of a file for the current user executing this command.

Perhaps better for your example would be

```
del /F /Q /S "%USERPROFILE%\blah.exe"
```